# Getting events older than 30 days from the Stripe API

Tags: javascript, api, stripe-payments

I've stupidly not been recording metadata passed to my server via a Stripe Webhook on a `checkout.session.completed` event. When attempting to retrieve this information directly from the Stripe API myself, I'm unable to get events older than 30 days.

From their [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list):

> List events, going back up to 30 days.

Which obviously doesn't bode well for my needs.

Trying this code using the [Stripe Node.js Library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node), I indeed only get events from the past 30 days:

```js
const events = stripe.events
    .list()
    .autoPagingToArray({limit: 10000})
```

Going to the Stripe web dashboard, I can see events past 30 days listed. But I need API access so I can process the results with code.

Does anybody know if it is possible to get ***all*** events (even past 30 days) via the Stripe API?

Comment: Same here. Still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get events that are older than 30 days via the API or otherwise.  https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list

Comment: I has already referenced the same docs in my question. Your "or otherwise" comment isn't strictly true, as I _am_ able to get events older than 30 days through the Stripe web interface.

Comment: Cool.  It's not possible to get all events via the Stripe API, which I believe was your question.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible with update stripe library for now.

```
const allNewCustomers = await stripe.customers
  .list({created: {gt: lastMonth}})
  .autoPagingToArray({limit: 10000});
```